# How to insert value into sql table while checking condition?

Tags: sql

I want to insert details of employees into sql table where salary is greater than 5000. How to write this query? Can I use where clause in insert query?

Comment: Which DBMS? What are the sample data? What is the expected output?

Comment: Give sample Tables values.source table and destination table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First we have to create employee table with CHECK constraint. 
For Example -

```
create table employee(varchar(45) ename, numeric salary CHECK(salary>5000));
```

Now we can insert into employee table. 
For Example -

```
insert into employee values('abc', 4000);
```

//it will not be inserted into employee table.

```
insert into employee values('xyz', 6000);
```

//it will be inserted into employee table.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to insert values of employees with salary greater than 5000, into another sql table. Here's what you can do:

```
INSERT INTO SOME_SQL_TBL (NAME, SALARY) 
   SELECT 
       NAME, SALARY 
   FROM 
       EMPLOYEES 
   WHERE 
       SALARY > 5000;
```

Answer (score 0):

For t-sql use this

```
Insert into destination_table_name (employeeId,salary) 
Select employeeId, salary from Employee where salary >5000
```